# how to restore a subsite after being deleted via powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, site, restore

I deleted a subsite by mistake using PowerShell but now I can't find it in Recycle Bin of the site collection. I used `Get-DeletedSite`, but I don't see the subsite there.

Anyone has got any idea how to restore this subsite?

Comment: did you check both recyclebins? end user and site collection admin?

Answer (score 2):

If the site is not available in 1st and 2nd stage recycle bin then that means it is gone completely.

Now the only option is to restore it from Backup. If you have backup of your site collection then restore just before you deleted the subsite.

- If you have content DB backup then restore it and using the Unattached Content Database recovery and export the desired site collection. After that import in to your site collection.
- If you have site collection backup then restore it to test/qa farm, from their export the subsite and import into your production site collection.